# Invalid security token locks out users trying to log in through an email link

Tags: joomla-3.x, login, .htaccess-configuration, security-token

I ran into the below problem that blocks my users to log into my site:

When the user needs to log in she gets a notification email with a button that links to the below address:
https://www.gonativeguide.com/de/backoffice/markavail?inquiry=437

Joomla changes the above link to the below one, asking the user to log in:
https://www.gonativeguide.com/de/component/users?view=login&Itemid=214

Previously this worked perfectly fine. But since yesterday, my users get the below error message:

> "Warnung Der Sicherheitstoken ist falsch. Die Anfrage wurde
> zurückgewiesen, um eine Sicherheitsverletzung zu verhindern. Bitte die
> Seite aktualisieren und erneut versuchen."

I believe this is equivalent to:

> "The most recent request was denied because it contained an invalid
> security token. Please refresh the page and try again"

I think I could find a workaround to the problem: If I log in by typing [www.gonativeguide.com/login](http://www.gonativeguide.com/login) and THEN click the link in the email, then it seems to be working. However it is super embarassing to ask my users to do so all the time, so I'd like to find a solution to the problem.

I read through the related (lengthy)forums talking about the invalid security token problem and tried the below suggestions, but none helped:

- Flush cache at the host
- Flush cache in Joomla
- Checking if the System - Page cache plugin is disabled (it was disabled)
- Empty the _session table in the Joomla database
- Upgrading Joomla to the latest version
- Fixing the database (Extensions / Manage / Database)
- Extending the session timeout to 10 hours

As a sidenote: a few days ago I added some new entries to the .htaccess file to redirect the non-www and http requests to https://www. Not sure if this has anything to do with the problem.

It seems that this is not a new issue, but please let me know, if based on the above description, you can suggest anything to fix this in my case.

Thanks,
W.

**UPDATE:** It turned out that the below .htaccess entry was causing the issue. Can somebody explain, what is wrong with this and how to write it properly to direct all requests to https://www...?

```
## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#

## Force https and www
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.gonativeguide\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.gonativeguide.com/$1 [L,R=301]

## Remove trailing slash if not directory
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://www.gonativeguide.com/$1 [R=301,L]

## End - Custom redirects
```

Comment: Under the Global Configuration settings menu item and the Site tab,  is there a value in the 'Cookie Settings' ? Both fields can be blank and I think this is the recommendation these days, but if you have a non https entry it maybe causing you issues. And have you changed the Force HTTPS setting under the Server tab to match your changes in the .htaccess?

Comment: thanks for the comments. Yes, the Cookie settings are blank. I was not aware of this Force HTTPS setting. I assume I should switch it to "Entire site", if .htaccess entry redirects all requests to https:://www..... Am I right? Thanks!

Comment: I changed the Force HTTPS setting to "Entire Site" but unfortunately the error is still reproducible.

Comment: Another thing that might help with your issue, or once it is fixed make it easier for your user, is to make sure the user selects 'Remember Me' when they login and that should avoid the login screen each time they click on a link in the email.

Comment: Again in your Global Configuration under the system Tab, do you have Session Handler set to PHP or Database? Database is the default but PHP is recommended. You mention clearing the __session table but that is not used if PHP is the session manager

Comment: And when was the last time you know it worked? You mentioned it 'since yesterday' but is that the day it first failed or when you first noticed it not working.  If you can narrow down the window between 'last worked' and 'not working' we can see if your .htaccess changes or some other changes have occurred.

Comment: Thanks again for the hints! Session handler is "Database". Shall I try to switch to PHP? OK, I will advise to tick the "Remember me" option. I got the first report from a user yesterday (29. July) that she cannot log in. A second one this morning. Interestingly some other user was still able to log-in this morning using the same link. Other users were able to log-in with the same link on the 28th of July.  I changed the .htaccess file on the 28th of July. Maybe I will try to remove the new .htaccess entries and see.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me! I commented out the .htaccess entry (added to post) and it works!!! Can anybody explain what was wrong with the .htaccess entry and how to write it properly, so that I don't have this problem with login, but still all requests go to https://www?

Comment: If you paste up your relevant .htaccess code I can take a look. If you switch over to PHP session handler everyone will have to re-login, including you.

Comment: The .htaccess looks right to me so it is likely to be some other conflict with the User and Joomla. You don't mention doing anything with the user like clearing their browser Cache or their Cookie for the site. You mention other people can login so this supports the idea the issue is more local to the user involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation and with the help of @Irata, it turned out that the new .htaccess entry was causing the problem. With this entry I can reproduce the issue 100%, removing the entry solves the problem. I don't know why this entry conflicts with the security token, but will close this ticket and open a new one for this question. Please see below the .htaccess entry:

```
## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#

## Force https and www
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.gonativeguide\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.gonativeguide.com/$1 [L,R=301]

## Remove trailing slash if not directory
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://www.gonativeguide.com/$1 [R=301,L]

## End - Custom redirects
```